# C# only be able to click on neighboring cells 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, multidimensional-array

I currently have a 2D array of the class Tile, (playfieldTiles[7,7]) and a 2D array of Pictureboxes, which are generated in Tile, with an onclick event, (playfieldPB[7,7,]). There is an array of neihgboring tiles (in the 2D array) on each instance of a Tile.
Each tile has a color, where Gray is the neutral color.

I need to be able to click on a tile to "select" a tile and only be able to click on one of the neighbors.

There are 49 instances of the tiles and pictureboxes in the array with each their own onclick event and neighbor array.

example:

[tile1][tile2][tile3]

[tile4][tile5][tile6]

[tile7][tile8][tile9]

Tile1's backColor is set to Red. 
I click on tile1 to select it. The neighbors of tile1 are {tile 2, tile 4, tile 5}. I want to be able to "copy" the color of tile 1 onto one of its neighbors by clicking on them. If I click on any other tile then one of its neighbors, I want the program to return "This tile is out of reach" and go back to selecting a tile.

How do I achieve this?

---

EDIT

I came up with the following (which doesn't quite work yet):

To each "Vakje" I added the following boolean:

isNeiborOff.

To a class "Playfield" I added the following boolean:

turnActive.

Although this doesn't work, this is what I have (not the complete solution):

```
public void SelectTile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playfieldClass.turnActive == false)
        {
            vakjePB.BackColor = Color.Green;
            playfieldClass.turnActive= true; //playfieldClass is an instance of class Playfield

            for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.Length; i++)
            {
                if (neighbors[i] != null)
                {
                    neighborsTiles[i].isNeighborOff = true;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isNeighborOff== true)
            {
                vakjePB.BackColor = Yellow
                ResetBurenBooleans();
                gamemanager.beurtBezig = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "This tile is out of reach");
                ResetIsNeighborOff(); //resets isNeighborOff boolean on each Tile.
                playfieldClass.turnActive= false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, this should make it so the first click selects a tile  and generates all neighbors for that specific tile using the "isNeighborOff" boolean. The second click will make the Tile Yellow if it IS a neighbor and returns "This Tile is out of reach" if it is not.

However, it always "selects" a Tile and it won't check if the second Tile clicked is out of reach or not. It seems to skip that part.

Just to clarify: I have the neighbors set up. the issue is that I cant "copy" the tile to one of its neighbors. The on click method doesn't enter the second part of looking if the Tile is a neighbor of the first Tile (using the "isNeighborOff" bool).

So what is wrong?

Comment: You've explained quite well what you're trying to achieve, but what is your question?

Comment: I want to know how to achieve this. I'll edit the post.

Comment: _"There is an array of neihgboring tiles (in the 2D array) in one instance of Tile"_ - Does that mean each Tile has references to all of its neighbours?

Comment: @fildor Yes, each tile has an array of neighbors

Comment: If that is the case, then you just need to check if the tile in the "second" click is in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to store all the possible combinations in advance, calculate what you need on the fly. Store the X,Y coordinates of the initial click. To color the neighboring cells, generate a list of the neighboring cells' X,Y coordinates based on the coordinates you stored for the initial click. A little looping can accomplish this quickly.

For the second click, since you're working with X,Y coordinates, testing whether the second cell is a neighbor of the first is easy: the target must be within -/+1 of the selected cell (but not the selected cell itself, of course).

Here's a console program to demonstrate. The output is:

```
Cell 3,1 neighbors 3,2? True
Cell 3,1 neighbors 5,4? False

For a grid of 7 x 7 cells:

Cell neighboring 0,0: 1,0
Cell neighboring 0,0: 0,1
Cell neighboring 0,0: 1,1
```

For the sake of brevity, `IsNeighbor` and `GetNeighborIndexes` are local functions, a feature of C# version 7. As a bonus, it'll work with a 2D array of any size.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Cell 3,1 neighbors 3,2? {IsNeighbor(3, 1, 3, 2)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Cell 3,1 neighbors 5,4? {IsNeighbor(3, 1, 5, 4)}");
    string[,] tiles = new string[7, 7];
    Console.WriteLine($"\nFor a grid of {tiles.GetLength(0)} x {tiles.GetLength(1)} cells:\n");
    var neighbors = GetNeighborIndexes(tiles, 0, 0);
    foreach(var n in neighbors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Cell neighboring 0,0: {n[0]},{n[1]}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();

    bool IsNeighbor(int selectedX, int selectedY, int testX, int testY)
    {
        if(testX == selectedX && testY == selectedY) return false;
        return (testX >= selectedX -1 && testX <= selectedX + 1) && (testY >= selectedY - 1 && testY <= selectedY + 1);
    }

    List<int[]> GetNeighborIndexes(object[,] data, int selectedX, int selectedY)
    {
        int xmax = data.GetLength(0) - 1;
        int ymax = data.GetLength(1) - 1;
        List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>(8);
        for(int yoffset = -1; yoffset < 2; yoffset++)
        {
            int y = selectedY + yoffset;
            if(y > -1 && y <= ymax)
            {
                for(int xoffset = -1; xoffset < 2; xoffset++)
                {
                    if(xoffset == 0 && yoffset == 0) continue; // selected pos
                    int x = selectedX + xoffset;
                    if(x < 0 || x > xmax) continue;
                    result.Add(new int[] { x, y });
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can understand, this is just to generate the neighbors, and although I needed a better algorithm for that, the issue is that only the first option of the click event (selecting a tile) will play. The second part, of actually "copying" the tile (color) doesn't do anything, it never gets to that point. The boolean can be set to true but it doesn't change anything the way the click event acts.